# How to setup an internal TCP load balancer?

Tags: google-compute-engine, terraform

I provisioned 5x VM instances and created an instance group for them (using Terraform) for a Riak cluster and now trying to setup an internal TCP load balancer. Accessing the load balancer ip just "hangs", no matter which port.

I did the following -

Created a an internal TCP load balancer under "Networking", set the backend to the instance group and created a TCP health check for the Riak port (8087), set a frontend for port 8087. under "Networking/Firewall rules" allowed traffic to `tcp:8087` from `130.211.0.0/22` for the health check service as per https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/internal/#health_check_firewall_rules.

When clicking on the load balancer after it was created, healthy says "/" which I don't understand.. I thought that maybe its something with the health checks and tried to open all traffic to `0.0.0.0/0`, which didn't help.

Finally, if clicking on the created health check under "Compute engine/Health checks", it just hangs...

What am I doing wrong and how can I actually create a working internal load balancer?

Comment: Where is your client VM? It must be in the same region as the forwarding rule for internal LB, otherwise it will "hang" until timeout.

Comment: both are in us-east1. I tried to create a load balancer again now and healthy shows "0/5" which is a change from just the "/" as before. also the health checks are not clickable under "Compute engine/health checks" (also a change from being clickable and hang as before). so something was definitely changed.

Comment: I guess the problem is with your health check settings, "0/5" means 0 out of 5 VMs are healthy. The forwarding rule considers your instances unhealthy, so it cannot forward traffic for you. Try to verify it from the client VM `curl http://<vm-internal-ip>:<health-check-port>`.

Comment: I can successfully connect to the service port, I also setup a micro instance with haproxy.. its just the internal TCP load balancer that I can't get to work..

Comment: Could you show your health check settings?

Comment: ```
gcloud beta compute health-checks describe riak-http
checkIntervalSec: 5
creationTimestamp: '2016-11-21T01:05:53.861-08:00'
description: ''
healthyThreshold: 2
httpHealthCheck:
  port: 8098
  proxyHeader: NONE
  requestPath: /ping
id: '3207645358899267102'
kind: compute#healthCheck
name: riak-http
selfLink: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/beta/projects/research-150008/global/healthChecks/riak-http
timeoutSec: 5
type: HTTP
unhealthyThreshold: 2
```

also tried an health check for the TCP port (8087) with the same result.. 
the firewall rule includes both.

Comment: Seems you configured the requestPath to /ping, so what is the result of `curl http://<vm-internal-ip>:8098/ping`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128745/discussion-between-dagang-and-gal-ben-haim).